# IronPython create function, getter and setter from c#

Tags: c#, function, ironpython, setter, getter

Can some one explain, how to pass an instance of an IronPython class to c# and add functions, getter and setter dynamically?

Currently i try and look at `PythonOps` and `MakeFunction`, but this seems not to be the way to go. Or am i wrong?